# string and path in C#

Tags: c#, string, path, uri

i have stucked on bellow problem in WPF C#.

Variable 'path' gets deserialized from xml file band contains following:

```
string path="D:\\test.mp4"
or
string path=@"D:\test.mp4"
uri i = new uri(path)
```

somehow path does not get recognized. Length is 12 instead of 11, i think because "\" does not get recongnized as path seperator. I have tried to sub string it and add it like this

```
string ss="D:" + @"\" + "test.mp4"
uri i = new uri(ss)
```

and still does not work. I tried with Path.combine also

Any idea?

Comment: Have you put a break point on it and seen the exact content of the string path?? What does it contain??

Comment: what about @"D:\test.mp4"?

Comment: http://shrani.si/f/11/KV/peLWfXN/2017-09-0316-31-55.jpg

Comment: everything is perfect in your image?

Comment: yes, everything is good, but first path has length of 11, but the second, same thing but length of 12 characters. And because of that uri is not recognizing it.  no idea why.

Comment: Where are you getting the actual error? Is it when you create the path, or is it happening when you are trying to access the file by the path (if that is the case, could you post the error)?

Answer (score 0):

I see you want to create a URI object and `D:/test.mp4` is not a URI string. hence, try this to see if it works:

```
string path="file://D:/test.mp4"
uri i = new uri(path)
```

Comment: Why should this be tried? How is it going to work? Some further explanation will benefit the person asking